# Matrix addition is comutative or not

Tags: matrix-equations

> Someone (Ph.D in Maths) told me that matrix addition(yes addition) is not comutative.

but how it is possible. He is wrong or right. If he is right then how?

*I'm 12 std. Student*

Comment: Matrix addition is always commutative. It is the multiplication that is not.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the only interesting aspect of it is that a PhD in math made such a false claim.

Comment: ? The OP wrote *matrix* addition.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri . As Anne Bauval pointed out and to be precise, OP wrote "matrix addition ***(yes addition)***".

Answer (score 3):

Interpreting $n\times n$-matrices by vectors of length $n^2$, matrix addition is just addition of vectors in a vector space $V$. Since $(V,+)$ is a commutative group (by definition of a vectors space), the addition is commutative.

Answer (score 0):

Addition of matrices is only defined for matrices with the same rows and colums. For two matrices $\mathbf{A} = \{ a_{ij} \}$ and $\mathbf{B} = \{ b_{ij} \}$ with the same rows and colums we have that $\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} = \{ a_{ij} + b_{ij} \}$. Therefore:

$$\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} = \{ a_{ij} + b_{ij} \} = \{ b_{ij} + a_{ij} \} = \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{A}$$

So matrix addition is commutative. For a reference you can check *Chapter 1, equation 2.2* from:

- *Harville, David A. Matrix Algebra from a Statistician’s Perspective. Springer, 2008.*